# Using jQuery to display multiple maps in an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps, iframe

I am trying to create a contact us page on a bootstrap framework where I have a row split into two columns. On the left hand side I have a  column containing an iframe which loads a google map. On the right hand side I have a  column containing the 4 offices addresses. By default the iframe loads the map of the head office by default.

I want to be able to click on one of the offices and the iframe content change to display the relevant mapping information.

The html on the page is as follows :-

```
<section id="contact-info">
    <div class="center">                
        <h2>How to Reach Us?</h2>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gmap-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 text-center">
                    <div class="gmap">
                        <iframe id="gmaps" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=JoomShaper,+Dhaka,+Dhaka+Division,+Bangladesh&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=joomshaper&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=42.766543,80.332031&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=JoomShaper,&amp;hnear=Dhaka,+Dhaka+Division,+Bangladesh&amp;ll=23.73854,90.385504&amp;spn=0.001515,0.002452&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=1073661719450182870&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-7 map-content">
                    <ul class="row">
                        <li class="col-sm-6">
                            <address>
                                <h5 id="office_01">Head Office</h5>
                            </address>

                            <address>
                                <h5 id="office_02">Office 2</h5>
                            </address>
                        </li>


                        <li class="col-sm-6">
                            <address>
                                <h5 id="office_03">Office 3</h5>
                            </address>

                            <address>
                                <h5 id="office_04">Office 4</h5>
                            </address>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>  <!--/gmap_area -->


<script src="js/mapmover.js"></script>
```

The jQuery is as follows :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#office02").click(function(){
        $("#gmaps").attr("src","https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=JoomShaper,+Dhaka,+Dhaka+Division,+Bangladesh&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=joomshaper&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=42.766543,80.332031&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=JoomShaper,&amp;hnear=Dhaka,+Dhaka+Division,+Bangladesh&amp;ll=23.73854,90.385504&amp;spn=0.001515,0.002452&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=1073661719450182870&amp;output=embed");
    });
});
```

Ideally I would like active maps rather than static images but all I get is a blank box. If I substitute the iframe 'src' for a normal webpage it works. I'm guessing it is something to do with the way google maps load into a page but this is beyond my normal scope as I have little knowledge of jQuery.

I initially tried using .html instead of .attr in the jQuery but it doesn't seem to like "'s in the source, which makes sense...

Anyone got any ideas or examples I could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, it's impossible to achieve what you are trying to do simply using iframe embedding google maps. What you are looking for is the [**google maps javascript api v3**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple). From there a function [**setCenter()**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) is probably what you are looking for if you are trying to interact with the map by setting up a on click listener to an element. Hope this helped!!!

Comment: I will look into this. It actually sounds like a much better way of handling the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction